# Let $f:G \longrightarrow G'$ be a group homomorphism. Prove that $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is a subgroup of $G'$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Can someone please verify this?

> Let $f:G \longrightarrow G'$ be a group homomorphism. Prove that $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is a subgroup of $G'$.

Let $a,b \in \operatorname{Im}(f)$. Then, there exist elements $x$ and $y$ in $G$ such that $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$. Since $f$ is a homomorphism,
\begin{equation}
f(x \cdot y) \in \operatorname{Im}(f)
\end{equation}
That is, \begin{eqnarray}
f(x) \cdot f(y) &\in& \operatorname{Im}(f) \\
a \cdot b &\in& \operatorname{Im}(f)
\end{eqnarray}
This shows that $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is closed under the operation $\cdot$. Also, since $f$ is a homomorphism, the identity element $e'$ of $G'$ belongs to $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ (a fact proved earlier). Moreover, every element $g$ in $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ has an inverse in $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ (a fact proved earlier). This completes the proof.

Comment: Looks perfect!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marc said, this looks good. However, I would change the statement

> Since $f$ is a homomorphism, $f(x\cdot y) \in \operatorname{Im}(f)$.

Is this really because $f$ is a homomorphism? Maybe it is and I just can't see it. I would argue that it follows because $G$ is a group under $\cdot$. As $x, y \in G$, $x\cdot y \in G$ so $f(x\cdot y) \in \operatorname{Im}(f)$.

Also, you shouldn't use $\cdot$ to denote the group operation in both $G$ and $G'$ as they could have different operations (i.e. $\phi: (\mathbb{R}, +) \to (\mathbb{R}_+, \cdot)$, $\phi(x) = e^x$).